# VBA: Referencing an image in IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to automate a download of a report. There's an image I need to press but I can't locate it by using getElementsByClassName, getElementsByTagName or getElementById. The code for the image is as follows:

```
<div class="right">
<a data-bind="click: function(){window.location = leads.list.url_get('.xls');}" style="cursor: pointer;"> <img data-bind="img: 'excel_36x36.gif'" data-fb-link="Excel Download" style="margin-top:-5px;margin-right:5px;" src="/assets/excel_36x36-55ac129b7404a6db9f6e3f43d2ec79982d1d89cdbc6d8d340befd029b4e79140.gif" width="24px"> </a>
Application Status: 
<select data-bind="value: leads.overall_status, options: [null, 'not_started', 'quoted_with_quotes', 'quoted_without_quotes', 'started', 'open_accounts'], optionsText: BrokerLeadsGridModel.overall_status_renderer" style="width: 160px;vertical-align: baseline;display: inline;" class="form-control"><option value="">Any</option><option value="not_started">Not Started</option><option value="quoted_with_quotes">Quoted</option><option value="quoted_without_quotes">No Quotes</option><option value="started">Started</option><option value="open_accounts">Open</option></select> 
Date Field: 
<select data-bind="value: leads.date_range_choice, options: ['created_at', 'terminal_at'], optionsText: BrokerLeadsGridModel.date_range_choices_text" style="width:125px; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline" class="form-control"><option value="created_at">Created At</option><option value="terminal_at">Terminal At</option></select> 
Date Range: 
<input data-bind="daterange: leads.daterange" spellcheck="false" class="form-control" style="margin-right:5px; width: 230px;vertical-align: baseline;display: inline;">
<img data-bind="img: 'refresh_22x22.png', click: leads.list.load" style="margin-top: -6px; cursor: pointer;" data-fb-button="Leads Grid Refresh" src="/assets/refresh_22x22-241f7c63a911337da4bb398fab9a562d155c836e077308c99908a9ed4e687e77.png">
</div>
```

My code currently doesn't do much other than help me to try and locate the correct element:

```
        Set imgCollection = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("img").Value

        For Each c In imgCollection
            MsgBox c
        Next
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can't access it using `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById` because it doesn't belong to a class nor does it have an ID.You can do it with `getElementsByTagName`.  What exactly have you tried? Posting your code and a bigger snippet of the HTML would help. You can use one of its attributes like `src`, if hardcoding its value wouldn't cause problems.

Comment: @joebody'sbusiness, check the example I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it really is the img to click you can use an attribute = value css selector to target. No loop required and browsers are optimized for css selection.

```
 appIE.document.querySelector("[data-fb-link='Excel Download']").click
```

For the other

```
appIE.document.querySelector("[data-fb-button='Leads Grid Refresh']").click
```

Comment: I was actually trying to click the _data-fb-button="Leads Grid Refresh"_ element, but this really helps with the next step in my code, thankyou!

Comment: Thankyou! Both these are brilliant, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code is working with your HTML and able to click that image.

VBA Code:

```
    Sub demo()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate ("D:\Backup20190913\tests\257.html")


    While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Dim oHDoc As HTMLDocument
    Set oHDoc = IE.document


    Dim iCnt As Integer
    Dim path As String
    path = "/assets/refresh_22x22-241f7c63a911337da4bb398fab9a562d155c836e077308c99908a9ed4e687e77.png"

        For iCnt = 0 To oHDoc.getElementsByTagName("img").Length - 1
            If path = oHDoc.getElementsByTagName("img").Item(iCnt).src Then
            oHDoc.getElementsByTagName("img").Item(iCnt).Click
            End If
        Next iCnt



   ' IE.Quit
   ' Set IE = Nothing
   ' Set oHEle = Nothing
   ' Set oHDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function abc()
{
   alert("image clicked...")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img onclick="abc()" data-bind="img: 'refresh_22x22.png', click: leads.list.load" style="margin-top: -6px; cursor: pointer;" data-fb-button="Leads Grid Refresh" src="/assets/refresh_22x22-241f7c63a911337da4bb398fab9a562d155c836e077308c99908a9ed4e687e77.png">

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Further, you can modify the code as per your own requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Deepak this works perfectly. I really appreciate your help!